# Agora Device manager creation failure in Unity mobile version

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, agora.io

Hellow

I tried to get device information from mobile build version with Unity framework.

Calling the CreateAVideoDeviceManager(), CreateAAudioRecordingDeviceManager(), CreateAAudioPlaybackDeviceManager() apis always results in false. So the device information cannot be displayed.

However, in the standalone version, it works normally.

Do you have any solution for the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

VideoDeviceManager and AudioDeviceManager are designed for standalone desktop environment only. It is in the documentation.